# Adding key:value pair in a dictionary within a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I add `key: value` pairs to a dictionary within a dictionary in Python? 
I need to take an input of a dictionary and sort the results by the type of the key:

```
new_d = {'int':{}, 'float':{}, 'str':{}}
temp = {}
for key in d:
    temp[key] = d[key]
    print temp
    if type(key) == str:
        new_d['str'] = temp
        temp.clear()
    elif type(key) == int:
        print 'int'
        temp.clear()
    elif type(key) == float:
        print 'float'
        temp.clear()
```

This is what I have and nothing is writing to the `new_d` dictionary.

Output should look like this

```
>>> new_d = type_subdicts({1: 'hi', 3.0: '5', 'hi': 5, 'hello': 10})
>>> new_d[int]
{1: 'hi'}
>>> new_d[float]
{3.0: '5'}
>>> new_d[str] == {'hi': 5, 'hello': 10}
True
"""
```

Comment: What do you want your output to look like?

Comment: what is `d` here could you be a little more clear on what the output should be for a given input

Comment: In the first code block, `new_d` has string keys. In the second code block, it has type keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a temporary dictionary for that. You can use the types directly as keys, too.

```
d = {1:'a', 'c':[5], 1.1:3}
result = {int:{}, float:{}, str:{}}
for k in d:
    result[type(k)][k] = d[k]
```

Result:

```
>>> result
{<class 'float'>: {1.1: 3}, <class 'str'>: {'c': [5]}, <class 'int'>: {1: 'a'}}
>>> result[float]
{1.1: 3}
```

If you want, you can use `collections.defaultdict` to automatically add keys of the necessary type if they don't yet exist, instead of hard-coding them:

```
import collections
d = {1:'a', 'c':[5], 1.1:3}
result = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for k in d:
    result[type(k)][k] = d[k]
```

Result:

```
>>> result
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {<class 'float'>: {1.1: 3}, <class 'str'>: {'c': [5]}, <class 'int'>: {1: 'a'}})
>>> result[float]
{1.1: 3}
```